# How to parse HTML using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: html, vb.net, html-agility-pack

i want to get weather data from that web site(http://www.mgm.gov.tr/?il=Bursa). I use this code

```
Dim Web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
    Dim Doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    Doc = Web.Load("http://www.mgm.gov.tr/?il=Bursa")
    For Each endeks1 As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='t4']/div/div[1]/div[4]/span[1]")
        MessageBox.Show(endeks1.InnerText, "oksd", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Next
```

but when i start my project something is wrong 
[myscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Ut2.png) How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Have you investigated to find out if there is an API available for that service? It could make your programming much easier.

Comment: There is no API